# How to print an image?

Tags: excel, vba, image, printing

I would like to print an image that shows in a frame on a userform.

```
frame1.Picture = LoadPicture(spath & xPicture & ".jpg")
```

`spath` is the full path to where the picture is stored.
This shows the picture.

I would like to print it.

Is there code to do this from a userform or is there code to print it from the file location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to call Windows Print dialog via shell command.

Example: (Full code)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, _
ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
As Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim MyPicFile As String: MyPicFile = "C:\Users\PortlandRunner\Pictures\excel.jpg"
    Call apiShellExecute(Application.hwnd, "print", MyPicFile, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim spath As String
    spath = "C:\Users\PortlandRunner\Pictures\excel.jpg"
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(spath)
End Sub
```

Form:

[image]

Clicking button opens Windows Office print dialog:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you so much.  Worked perfectly.

Comment: Would you know how I might add a caption to this picture, such as identifying the scene or the jpg file name?

Comment: Good question, my initial attempt was not successful.  I'd suggest posting a new question as I may not have time to get back to this for a while.

Comment: Can you add printing of multiple images?

Comment: @dangalg - I've never tried before but it looks like it's not so easy.  Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44073316/2521004). Maybe worth putting a bounty on that one and seeing if someone has a way around it.